# Syntax error near 'User' kills me

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get

> "Incorrect syntax near 'User'"

in the INSERT line.
Cant figure out whats wrong??

Thanks in advance.

```
create proc RegUserlogon

@username nvarchar(50),
@date Timestamp,
@iPAdress nvarchar(50)

as
BEGIN
insert INTO Logins(User,Date,IPAdress)
values(@username, @date,@iPAdress)
END
```

Answer (score 5):

[**`USER`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) is a *reserved* keyword in `Sql Server`. Use *Square brackets* to escape it

```
insert INTO Logins([User],Date,IPAdress)
values(@username, @date,@iPAdress)
```

Always it is better to avoid using *keywords* as `identifiers`

Comment: As is Date - I would escape that also. Whenever I am creating table, I try and avoid naming columns any type of reserved word.

Comment: @Leonidas199x - Not in Sql Server

Comment: @Leonidas199x Oddly enough, `Date` doesn't cause issues when used as a column name.

Comment: @Siyual - Nothing odd here. `Date` isn't a reserved keyword in Sql Server

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql My error, it is not currently, but it is advised not to use it, as it will be.

Comment: @Leonidas199x - True.. Have added it in my answer